# Angular Recursive Component with *ngFor and async pipe goes in loop

Tags: angular, recursion, tree, observable, ngfor

I was trying to create a dynamic content tree in angular. Like below.

```
vehicles
  - cars
     - vw
       - golf
       - passat
     - ford
       - fiesta
     - toyota
  - Buses
    - volvo
    - Scania
Animals
  - carnivorous
    - Lion
    - tiger
  - Herbivorous
    - Cow
    - Horse
```

I have a content-tree component and a tree-node component. I was trying to create the children in the tree dynamically depending on the number of chapters. As the DocRootNode is an observable, I have to use async pipe in the code.And i used the tree node recursively to create dynamic tree.

content-tree.html:

```
<tree-node *ngFor="let docChildNode of DocRootNode$ | async"
                 [node]="docChildNode">
</tree-node>
```

tree-node.html:

```
  <div class="children" *ngIf="node.children">
    <tree-node *ngFor="let childDocNode of node.children" [node]="childDocNode" >
    </tree-node>
  </div>
```

Everything is working as intended. But I found an issue that in background the recursion is going in loop. for ex: I added `[ngClass] = "{ isActive: isActive(node) }"` and in the isActive function, I did a console log and I found that the log is going in loops. I couldn't find the reason. I am new to Angular. Any help is highly appreciated.

Updating the Log. the number are the nodes

```
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 4
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 6
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-1-0

tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 4
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 6
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-1-0

tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 4
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 6
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-0-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-0
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-0-2-2
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-1
tree-node.component.ts:78 This one 3-1-1-0
```

Adjo

Comment: What does it mean "goes in loop"? Please share the console log output and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: the logs are repeated and the page hangs

Comment: Please consider creating a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) if possible

Comment: Updated the logs.

Comment: Might be an issue with angular not being able to properly detect changes to the object(s). Have you tried adding a `trackBy` expressions to your `ngFor`s?

Comment: I just tried, But the result is same @naeramarth7

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at rendering the nodes starting from the parent node.

```
export interface TreeNode<T> {
    value: T;
    children: Array<TreeNode<T>>;
    parent?: TreeNode<T>;
}
```

Given your input you will render this tree.

```
vehicles
  - cars
     - vw
       - golf
       - passat
```

or

```
{
    value: 'vehicles',
    children: [
        {
            value: 'cars',
            children: [
                {
                    value: 'vw',
                    children: [
                        {
                            value: 'golf',
                            children: [],
                            parent: /* linked to 'vw' node */
                        },
                        {
                            value: 'passat',
                            children: [],
                            parent: /* linked to 'vw' node */
                        }
                    ],
                    parent: /* linked to 'cars' node */
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    parent: undefined /*or null*/
}
```

You will need to assign the parent node using breadth first algorithm.

The template below will now be able to render the tree you created.
It will get the top most node and display the name.

Using the  and *ngTemplateOutlet we're able to send the list of children nodes to the  to render by setting the $implicit value of the context.
In the ng-template we will then have some logic to render the name and recursively call the same ng-template if it has children. This is what will create your tree.

You will have to add the correct styling suited for your application.

```
<div *ngIf="tree?.value">
    <h2> {{tree.value.name}}</h2>
</div>
<div *ngIf="tree?.children">
    <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
        <div *ngFor="let node of list">
            <h5>{{node.value.name}}</h5>
            <div *ngIf="node.children.length > 0">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: node.children }"></ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: tree.children }"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Docs:
https://angular.io/api/common/ngTemplateOutlet
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: could you explain a bit more.

Comment: This logic will create one tree at a time from the top parent node. So you will need to have a higher level component to render a list of trees and it will work.